# Remove Empty Html Attributes in C# using Regex

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have some html like the below:

```
<img src="/web/20110208042711im_/http://coralifeaqualight.com/wp-content/themes/xtheme/images/coralife-aqualight-pro.png" alt="">
```

What I want to be able to do is use regex to clear any html attributes that have no value, in this case: alt="".
I cannot figure out how to look for any string that with a space and contains ="" as that would do it for me, does anyone know

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/113586

Answer (score 1):

Parsing HTML with Regex is generally considered a bad idea as there is too many edge cases. Read for yourself. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

A favored solution is [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples)

Also see this Stackoverflow question about the usage of Regex for HTML: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no regex genius, but I believe `String.Replace("\s\w+=\"\"", String.Empty)` would do it, if you've got that whole tag in a string.